# Need help in configuring Azure DNS for www.domain.com without affecting mail.domain.com

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a domain and webapp currently which I need to do a set up for the domain to point to my webapp server. I only need to point to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to my Azure DNS and mail.domainname.com point to another email provider. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you any using transfer protocol.

Comment: no I'm not using any

Comment: It can be possible with the DNS zones in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DNS is primarily used to host your DNS domain and manage your DNS records.

The advantages of hosting your domains on Azure is that you can manage your DNS records using the same credentials, APIs, tools, and billing as your other Azure services.

Since you are not using any transfer protocol, the below steps can be followed without affecting your domain.

As this is a domain redirection, we need to use DNS zones.

1. Create DNS zone.

[image]

2. Add a record set using NS type

[image]

[image]

Enter the host names accordingly as per your requirement.

[image]

Alongside, we can use **nslookup** to validate whether the  names are working or not.

Reference taken from [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns)